# ISO Date function working on date having 0 in time but not with proper time

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, isodate

I am trying to search some data in collection so i add `{dCreatedAt: ISODate('2022-11-16')}` in filter so i have two data having following values in db

```
dCreatedAt: 2022-11-16T00:00:00.000+00:00,
dCreatedAt: 2022-11-15T13:31:18.513+00:00
```

Filter showing only first data not the second one.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Only the first document matches your condition...

Comment: Sorry by mistake i write 15 in second one it must be 16

Answer (score 1):

If you really want, you can use an aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {$dateTrunc: {date: "$dCreatedAt", unit: "day"}},
          {$dateFromString: {dateString: "2022-11-16"}}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7mUOlgEG0S4)

Comment: You can directly put the `$expr` in a `find` for this case like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3sozJ-lCuo1) :)

Comment: Thanks @ray, even better

Comment: I am getting  Unrecognized expression '$dateTrunc'

Comment: What is your mongodb version? `$dateTrunc` is since version 5.0